# BIND DKIM syntax error

Tags: email, dns, bind, dkim, dmarc

I'm trying to implement DKIM in the DNS zone file. I'm encountering a "Syntax Error" when the following entry is added to the zone file of the domain:

```
 201803._domainkey IN TXT “v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; s=email p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7HHm8nxsNbhzBIUd/dgbWFvMfbDmr+GREZ3uOSJ8kbadnK4i14XYBNkNGrwYG+zNkeS4xa37MeQT6TMFmq4v5zkWwrKKhoFqpoQCwv85BCFNyE0wMpFJr0PJ4zIqSv0QbFSt/tbsZQz4sO1WqFKikLY8kA8V/CNi6exkB+gkcz87ny3gND52AaTqAJJ4cbNBuA61m3OWI+lCo4kHHlB+9rQSX4ujOy7K5ljsnXUxWHRK5DpSLArg0FM7YduL3dKEh2Rgp1nDSuyIsbuCqhwlx9flnH5KyzXJ6DNv4LUPu7XySnQSUvvusL/ShwsbmGE2eT8rI22AZIjigMdKVHXUQQIDAQAB;"
```

The error i'm receiving is as follows:

```
dns_rdata_fromtext: forward/DOMAIN_NAME.db:183: syntax error
```

I have read a lot about how to implement DKIM yet and already omitted unnecessary parameters such as "h" and "s".

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You did not omit `s` as you have `s=email`, but then you are missing the semi colon after it and before the `p=` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong starting double quote `“` character. remove it and re-add a proper double quote.

Also some DNS service providers have limit of 255 character on number of characters in TXT record, So for that you will have to create a smaller size ssh key.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.